# How to pass numerical and categorical features to RandomForestRegressor in Apache Spark: MLlib in Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, regression, random-forest

How to pass numerical and categorical features to RandomForestRegressor in Apache Spark: MLlib in Java?

I'm able to do it with numerical or categorical, but I don't know how to implement it together.

My working code is as follows (only numerical features used for prediction)

```
String[] featureNumericalCols = new String[]{
        "squareM",
        "timeTimeToPragueCityCenter",
};
String[] featureStringCols = new String[]{ //not used
        "type",
        "floor",
        "disposition",
};
VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(featureNumericalCols).setOutputCol("features");
Dataset<Row> numericalData = assembler.transform(data);
numericalData.show();
RandomForestRegressor rf = new RandomForestRegressor().setLabelCol("price")
       .setFeaturesCol("features");
// Chain indexer and forest in a Pipeline
Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline()
    .setStages(new PipelineStage[]{assembler, rf});
// Train model. This also runs the indexer.
PipelineModel model = pipeline.fit(trainingData);
// Make predictions.
Dataset<Row> predictions = model.transform(testData);
```

Comment: Have you looked at [VectorIndexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorIndexer)? Here is an example in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#random-forest-regression)

Comment: Thank you for an advice, I had a look at it, but it appears I can pass him only one column (setInputCol) but not multiple (setInputCols)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone out there, this is the solution:

```
    StringIndexer typeIndexer = new StringIndexer()
            .setInputCol("type")
            .setOutputCol("typeIndex");

    preparedData = typeIndexer.fit(preparedData).transform(preparedData);

    StringIndexer floorIndexer = new StringIndexer()
            .setInputCol("floor")
            .setOutputCol("floorIndex");

    preparedData = floorIndexer.fit(preparedData).transform(preparedData);

    StringIndexer dispositionIndexer = new StringIndexer()
            .setInputCol("disposition")
            .setOutputCol("dispositionIndex");

    preparedData = dispositionIndexer.fit(preparedData).transform(preparedData);

    String[] featureCols = new String[]{
            "squareM",
            "timeTimeToPragueCityCenter",
            "floorIndex",
            "floorIndex",
            "dispositionIndex"
    };

    VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(featureCols).setOutputCol("features");

    preparedData = assembler.transform(preparedData);

 //    ... some more impelemtation details

    RandomForestRegressor rf = new RandomForestRegressor().setLabelCol("price")
            .setFeaturesCol("features");

    return rf.fit(preparedData);
```